# Set subquery result as default value

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, psql

I want to do the next:

```
ALTER TABLE bets 
ADD COLUMN owner_id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT (SELECT min(user_id) FROM users);
```

I'm confused postgres does not allow to save `SELECT min(user_id) FROM users` subquery's result to a variable and then reuse it.

*Any ideas how to set subquery result as default value?*

P.S. `bets` table is not empty

Comment: @jarlh could you provide an example pls? Which kind of trigger it should be? The problem is that `bets` table is not empty

Comment: What is the users table that the min(user_id) should be default for this field? It doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: @MichaelZ. I need to initialize `owner_id` with some value which points to `users` table. But this is migration script, and I do not know from which number user ids start

Comment: Yeah, but aren't you just setting all values bets.owner_id = min(user_id)? That's where I'm lost. Will the min(user_id) change? I can see max(user_id) changing.

Comment: @MichaelZ. yes, `min(user_id)` could be changed since we're using test environments, where generated user ids may start from 1000

Comment: This might help you implement a trigger http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_triggers.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
create function my_foobar_default(OUT id uuid)
as 'select id from foobar order by X desc limit 1'
language sql

alter table Y
add column if not exists SOMEVALUE uuid not null default my_foobar_default()
```